# Where can I find a recording of rig ved chating with correct swara pronunciation?

Tags: vedas, samhita

Where can I find a recording of rig or yujur veda chanting where swaras like udatta, anudatta, etc. are correctly pronounced?

According to Yudhistira Mimamsaka in his book Vaidik Swara Mimamsa, swaras like udatta, anudatta etc. in the recent years have gone extinct in Veda chanting tradition (they are now only indicated by hand). There exist only a few Brahmans who can pronounce them accurately.

That's why I am curious to hear what these swaras actually sound like. So, does there exist such a recording?

I have listened to various recordings of rig veda and yajur veda on archive.org and youtube.com but unfortunately haven't come across one recording yet where these swaras are pronounced correctly and consistently with the exception of one (but that one is too small, less than 1 minute).

**Extras:**
[Here's](https://archive.org/details/chanakya-episode-26) the short recording I found which I believe pronounce the udatta, anudatta correctly.

Comment: you probably have to visit a gurukula/veda-patashala for that. they purposely don't record it because it can be broadcast to all audiences.

Answer (score 1):

Vedas Chanting Audio App on Google Play - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.resun.chantingvedas

Answer (score 0):

This website has recordings of the Vedas https://vedicheritage.gov.in/

Here's a link for the Rigveda: https://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/rigveda/shakala-samhita/mandal-01/

Comment: Do they use the correct pronunciation?

Comment: They are part of the Keralan tradition of Vedic chanting. I'm not an expert in Vedic chanting but I would assume, because they were funded by the Indian government to do this, that they chant a version that would be correct (at least within the Keralan tradition). 

What I can say with certainty is that they do chant with intonations that match the accompanying tonally annotated Vedic Sanskrit written below the videos.